# Can't build RDCOMClient using rtools40 and R 4.0

Tags: c++, r, rdcomclient, rtools

A while back, I created a fork of the RDCOMClient package to keep it working with R 3.6 (https://github.com/dkyleward/RDCOMClient). People are now running into issues again because it won't work with R 4.0. The problem doesn't seem as easy to fix, and I'm hoping for some help.

If I flip Rstudio back to R 3.6 (and rtools35), I can use the package after installing with `devtools::install_github()`. When I try in R 4.0 (and rtools40), the package builds and I can connect over COM to an application. The first line of code below works, and `xl` is a COM pointer; however, trying to do anything with it (like set Excel to visible) will crash R.

```
xl <-  RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xl[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
```

Again, the above works in R 3.6.

Is there is a way to continue building with the previous rtools? I came across https://github.com/r-windows/rtools-backports#readme, which talks about using rtools35 to keep building packages, so I have hope, but I don't understand how to make it happen.

Alternatively, if there are minor changes I can make to the R or cpp code that will solve my problem, I'm all ears. I'm a cpp novice, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rik's answer was incredibly helpful and got a version working; however, after spending a day on it, I was able to improve on it. I want to put that here in case I have to do it again. The main improvement is being able to build a working package for both 32- and 64-bit architectures. By default, R installs both, and this makes things easier when installing dependent packages.

The first two steps are the same:

Install R-4.0.0 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.0/R-4.0.0-win.exe)

Install Rtools35 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe) in directory c:\Rtools

If (like me) you had already installed rtools40, a system environment variable named `RTOOLS40_HOME` is created. The first step is to change that to:

`C:\rtools`

If you don't have rtools40 installed, then create the `RTOOLS40_HOME` system environment variable.

Two changes are still needed in the make files. These are found in your R installation directory.

In `etc\x64\Makeconf`, add underscores to match the rtools35 directory structure by setting these values:

```
MINGW_PREFIX = /mingw_$(WIN)
BINPREF ?= "$(RTOOLS40_ROOT)/mingw_64/bin/"
```

Do the same in `etc\i386\Makeconf`:

```
MINGW_PREFIX = /mingw_$(WIN)
BINPREF ?= "$(RTOOLS40_ROOT)/mingw_32/bin/"
```

**Do not** set `BINPREF` as an environment variable, or this will overwrite the makefile changes (like `RTOOLS40_HOME` does). With these complete, finish off with the same steps that Rik outlined:

Open windows command prompt and change to the directory that contains the RDCOMClient subdirectory and type:

`R CMD INSTALL RDCOMClient –-build RDCOMClient.zip`

This installs RDCOMClient in the local installation of R-4.0.0 and additionally creates the file RDCOMClient_0.94-0.zip that can be installed on other systems using the following command:

`install.packages("RDCOMClient_0.94-0.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")`

Comment: Thanks for providing the already compiled binary on your Github page! I want to reproduce your approach for another package. Did you uninstall RTools4.0 before installing RTools3.5 or did you just install both?

Comment: Both are installed

Answer (score 7):

This was a quick fix :

> install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")

Comment: I'm running R 4.0 as of 1/18/2021 and this worked wonderfully for me. Thank you for posting this solution.

Comment: I'm on R 4.1.3 as of 13-05-2022 it is failed to compile (only source is possible as bin is for 3.x)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install R-4.0.0
2. Install Rtools35
3. Edit $R_HOME/etc/x64/Makeconf (for R-4.0.0-x64)
4. Rcmd INSTALL RDCOMClient

Comment: Thanks for answering. Using this approach could work for me, but it seems like everyone would have to do this. Package dependencies also wouldn't work as easily. I guess I could compile the binary, put it up as a GitHub release, and then have others install it using install.packages(url = "...").

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the procedure delineated in the answer above leads in the right direction but a few extra steps may be required. I can also confirm that the procedure below produces a Windows binary file that can be installed and will run under R-4.0.0:

Install R-4.0.0 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.0/R-4.0.0-win.exe)

Install Rtools35 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe) in directory c:\Rtools

Edit $R_HOME/etc/x64/Makeconf (for R-4.0.0-x64) by changing

```
##  The rtools40 installer sets RTOOLS40_HOME, default to standard install path
RTOOLS40_HOME ?= c:/rtools40
```

to

```
##  The rtools40 installer sets RTOOLS40_HOME, default to standard install path
RTOOLS40_HOME ?= c:/rtools
```

Download RDCOMClient-master.zip from https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient (click the green Clone button and select download zip)

Unpack to a directory named RDCOMClient

Ensure that the following PATH variables are set:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64 (assuming this is the location where R is installed)
C:\Rtools\bin
C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin
```

Add environment variable BINPREF with the following value (the final slash is important):

```
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/
```

Open windows command prompt and change to the directory that contains the RDCOMClient subdirectory and type:

```
R CMD INSTALL RDCOMClient –-build RDCOMClient.zip
```

This installs RDCOMClient in the local installation of R-4.0.0 and additionally creates the file RDCOMClient_0.94-0.zip that can be installed on other systems using the following command:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient_0.94-0.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

Comment: This works with one minor typo corrected: change the last period in "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin.x64" to a backslash: "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64". Also, to be safe, I'd make sure to specify to set system environment variables. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using R 4.1.2 and I found RDCOMClient will crash the R Session and the above solutions were not working.

Then, I further check with the source owner and found out the solution.

> https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/36

Duncantl gave the solution and it works.

```
dir.create("MyTemp")
remotes::install_github("BSchamberger/RDCOMClient", ref = "main", lib = "MyTemp")
```

If that is successful, we can then load the newly installed package with

```
library("RDCOMClient", lib.loc = "MyTemp")
```

Answer (score 0):

although this post is a bit older but i also stumbled across it since i had a similar issue.
what worked for me at the end was the following command in the R console:

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
```

i had to install a lot of other packages to be able to run it but that you will get from the warning messages from R.
I am using R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)