# RDCOMClient with COMCreate("Outlook.Application") crashing R

Tags: r, outlook, devtools, rdcomclient

I'm using the package RDCOMClient with R version 4.0.2.   It was downloaded using:

`devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")`

I'd like to use the package for reading and writing email.  I've started this way:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
folderName <- "AUX"
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
```

However, when I try to use any method from OutApp, R crashes, regardless of whether I'm using console R or RStudio.  For example:

```
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
```

```
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
```

Either of these code chunks cause R to encounter a fatal error and the session to be terminated.   No errors/warnings along the way, just an immediate crash.  `str(OutApp)` returns that OutApp is of formal class `COMIDispatch` [package "RDComClient"] with 1 slot (.. @ ref:).  OutApp is of length 1 and mode S4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/24#issuecomment-654439280

You can choose which version of R to use by holding `ctrl` when opening R studio. R3.6 works for me

Comment: See [RDCOMClient#26](omegahat/RDCOMClient), and a suggested workaround (for R-4) in https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/24#issuecomment-654439280 (as @BillAsh just suggested).

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-session-aborted-rdcomclient/66509

Comment: Follow-on link from BillAsh's link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61735315/3358272

Answer (score 4):

A minimal commit was created by a helpful user, due to which the code in OP will work for R > 4.0.

Use the following installation:

```
library(remotes) 
remotes::install_github("BSchamberger/RDCOMClient", ref = "main")
```

More discussion at [this](https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/24#issuecomment-723312770) link.